# Using regexp_extract in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to find the rows from a hive table where a particular column does not contain null values or \N values or STX character '\002'. The objective is to find which rows contain some characters other than these three.

I tried this hive query:

```
    select column1,length(regexp_replace(column1,'\N|\002|NULL','')) as value         
    FROM table1 LIMIT 10;
```

I was expecting zero in the following cases but I am getting the following:

```
    column1 value
    NULL    NULL
            0
    NULL    NULL
            0
    \N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N        8
    NULL    NULL
    \N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N        8
    NULL    NULL
    NULL    NULL
    \N\N\N  3
```

Could someone please help me on the correct regex for the above case?

Thank you.

Ravi

Comment: What is the data type of column 1 ?

Comment: Date type for column1 is String

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the slashes? eg: `\\N|\\002|NULL`

Comment: I tried that but getting the following error: Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\N|\002|NULL

Comment: Are those `\N` new lines or a literal `\` followed by `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that hive is using Java's regular expression engine so the problem seems to be with the regex itself, more specifically in the escape sequences.

Try the following and if it doesn't work then please let me know:

```
(?:(?:\\\\N)+|\002|NULL)
```